How to create a query to view number of guests between dates on Mysql
I have a series of reservation on a booking system and I would like to create a view that would show how many guest are in a given date interval (for example: from 2024-11-01 until 2024-12-31) that the user could select to check the 'head count' in that time period.
The issue I'm having is that my query will not add/sum the number of guests on overlaping dates.
I have the following tables on my database:
reservations
id_res  checkin         checkout
1       2024-11-08      2024-11-12
2       2024-12-13      2025-01-06
3       2024-12-17      2025-01-10
4       2024-12-20      2025-01-11
5       2024-12-27      2025-01-09

guests
id_guest    name
1           Joe
2           Mary
3           Anne
4           John
5           Paul
6           Dan
7           Peter

rel_reservations_guests
id_r     id_res         id_guest
1          1            1
2          2            2
2          2            4
2          2            4
2          2            5
2          2            7
2          3            4
3          3            5
3          3            6

Here is my query so far:
SELECT r.id_res, r.checkin, r.checkout, COUNT(rc.id_guest) AS total_guests
FROM reservations AS r
INNER JOIN rel_reservations_guests AS rc ON rc.id_res = r.id_res 
INNER JOIN guests AS g ON g.id_guest = rc.id_guest 
WHERE  r.checkin >= '2024-11-01'
GROUP BY r.checkin
ORDER BY r.checkin ASC

My query Result:
id_res      checkin         checkout        total_guests
1           2024-11-08      2024-11-12      1
2           2024-12-13      2025-01-06      5
3           2024-12-17      2025-01-10      2 
4           2024-12-20      2025-01-11      3 

My intended result:
Date          total_guests
2024-11-08      1
2024-11-09      1
...
2024-12-13      5
2024-12-14      5
...
2024-12-17      8
...

Thanks!

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range for how to write a subquery that generates all dates in a range. Then you can join that with the reservations table to match all reservations that include each date.

Thanks @Barmar I'll check that possibility. Not sure why they closed my question as a duplicate and posted a question that is not the same! Bummer!

"They" was me. I have multiple duplicates in my cache for questions related to date sequences.

OH! I see. :D Just thought that there was a specificity to my question that would differ from the others since is not only about date interval, but also the count of records that that should be carried throughout the dates... but I'll keep trying to solve it.

Just want to put it out there that I found what I was looking for here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/283560/315442
